Pywebio user interference in memory
Dataframe in memory is not unique to each user in Pywebio. So if two users login with different logins, one would expect each to have their own copy of a dataframe (df) so that each can update without interference with the other. However this is not what occurs. I tried logging on my local PC (running Pywebio app locally) with two different browsers (ensuring all cookies deleted), with two different user logins. I found that if one user updates df the other received the same updates in their df.
